# Array Data in CGridView - Yii

Tags: php, arrays, yii

Everyone...

**I'm using yii 1.1.x**

I have an array(Which is got from a query and foreach loops) This array need to be shown in CGridView. I already tried with CArrayDataProvider(it's just showing Displaying 1-6 of 6 results with no gridview table). If I print($dataProvider->getData();)

```
Array(
[abc] => 27
[def] => 27
[ghi] => 27
[jkl] => 27
[mno] => 12
[pqr] => 2  )
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using an array as the data-source for CGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538777/using-an-array-as-the-data-source-for-cgridview)

Comment: I already tried that one also.not working for me